# Drone SDK supporting free-flight control

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dji-sdk, dronekit

This is my first time getting into drones.
I am looking at DJI drones, currently as it seems most promising from a documentation and reviews point of view.

Basically, I would like to program a drone(s) to fly a certain pattern and take pictures when a certain criteria is met. For example, I would like the drone to take off and fly around a small park, stopping to take a picture of each tree it encounters, automatically (auto-piloted / driven by some "AI").

Now I glanced thru the DJI SDK documentation, and so far it SEEMS this is possible (via FlightControl class). But im not sure.

**Question:**

Can my requirements be met with current drone SDK technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  the correct SDK,  4.11.1 will do everything you mentioned. You will need to do some location calculations but that's about it.

The sample will almost do everything you want as-is, with minor changes.

Comment: Wow. When you say it can do almost everything as-is, i am assuming this is excluding the part of detecting a tree...etc.?

Comment: So it seems like you are referring to the Mobile SDK (4.11). I noticed the Windows SDK is only in beta. Does this necessarily mean that the Mobile SDK is more advanced and thus have more advanced features than the beta Windows SDK?

Answer (score 0):

With the DJI Mobile SDK you can use the Mission classes to automatically fly a given set of coordinates (waypoints) and do some actions once you arrive at a waypoint, e.g. take a picture.

However the SDK has limitations:

- The SDK is unable to detects objects in the video stream. Therefore it is needed to use your own code to detect objects yourself.
- The way the drone flies to the waypoint is quite limited, e.g. the drone will always face the camera in the direction of flight.
- When using the DJI Mission classes, a change of the route during execution is only possible with the use of timeline Missions by adding timeline elements to the list.

As you already assumed in the comment: Yes, the Mobile SDK is more advanced than Windows SDK.